# Websocket and refresh token issue

Tags: websocket, jwt, token, keycloak

Currently I'm using keycloak in my application that uses websocket. However, when I establish the websocket using atmosphere library in the frontend, I pass as a header the token after authentication. The token at that time is active and the connection gets establish without an issue.

However, if my token expires and I receive a refresh token, the websocket channel still holds the old token since I haven't refreshed my browser and hence I receive an error saying that the token is not active when I try to send a websocket message.

The only way I find to attach the new token is to actually re-establish the websocket connection and append the new token in the headers but that's not what I want to do.

Is there a way to keep the token updated into an ongoing websocket channel ?

This question has been a discussion in some topics but I couldn't extract a solution for this.

Thank you

Comment: For people who are facing the same issue, this is how I bypassed it.

Create an API call that would be triggered once the token gets refreshed and the middleware would store the user principal coming within that api call in a cache.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue.
Is there no other way to refresh the token in the header? Really sad :/

Comment: No..

What I did was the following:-

An API request to middleware with the new token, I cache it.
And then for each websocket message, when I want to check the token of something I rely on the cached value.